# Advice on Unit testing a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I have written a Windows Forms application and now I want to write some unit tests for it (not exactly test driven development seeing as I am writing the tests after I have developed but better late then never!) My question is that with such an application how do you go about writing the unit tests, given that nearly all of the methods and events are private? I have heard of NUnit Forms but I hear good and bad things about it, also there has been no real development on that project for a while so it looks abandoned. Also is it generally accepted that the project have have adequate unit testing in place if I wrote unit test cases for all of the events that a user would trigger by clicking/ pressing buttons, or would I have to go and write unit test cases for all methods and figure out a way to test my private methods?

**EDIT:** My business logic is seperated from my presentation logic, there is 1 or 2 public methods my business logic exposes so the form can access them, but what about all the private methods that are in the business logic?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to ensure that you have proper separation of your business logic from your form.  Basically, using an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  Then, you can easily test everything outside the form, as if the form didn't even exist.

Now, this could still leave some untested form-specific functionality.  I.E., is the form wired-up to the service correctly?  For this, then you could still consider something like NUnit Forms or another alternative.

Comment: OK I have that, but if I have 1 or 2 public methods in my business logic that my form accesses, and these in turn access private methods in my business logic, is it enough to test the public interface to my form in the business logic? And not write unit tests that test any of my private methods directly?

Comment: @Jim - Yes, that is considered acceptable my many, as testing the public methods is exercising the code within the private methods.  (It really wouldn't be much different than removing the private methods, and moving their code to inner blocks within the public methods.)

Comment: MVC alone does not ensure the testing of what he wants to test. He may implement the MVC pattern but if the business logic in the controllers is inside the Form project they would still be internal. If he moves it to an external project then what he wanted internal would now be public and therefore no longer "protected" even though nothing is fully secret.

Answer (score 44):

The key to Unit Testing graphical applications is to make sure that all  of the business logic is in a separate class and not in the code behind.

Design patterns like [Model View Presenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) and [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) can help when designing such a system.

To give an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMyView
{
    MyPresenter Presenter;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Presenter = new MyPresenter(this);
    }

    public string SomeData
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            MyTextBox.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Presenter.ChangeData();
    }
}

public interface IMyView
{
    string SomeData { get; set; }
}

public class MyPresenter
{
    private IMyView View { get; set; }
    public MyPresenter(IMyView view)
    {
        View = view;
        View.SomeData = "test string";
    }

    public void ChangeData()
    {
        View.SomeData = "Some changed data";
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Form only has some infrastructure code to tie everything together. All your logic is inside your Presenter class which only knows about a View Interface.

If you want to unit test this you can use a Mocking tool like [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Documentation.ashx) to mock the View interface and pass that to your presenter.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestChangeData()
{
    IMyView view = MockRepository.DynamickMock<IMyView>();
    view.Stub(v => v.SomeData).PropertyBehavior();

    MyPresenter presenter = new MyPresenter(view);

    presenter.ChangeData();

    Assert.AreEqual("Some changed data", view.SomeData);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Break out all business logic into a separate project and unit test that. Or at least move all logic from the forms into separate classes.

Answer (score 6):

You have a few options.

1. Use a tool like Coded UI to test via your user interface. This isn't a great option, because it's slower than unit testing and the tests tend to be more brittle.
2. Separate your business logic from your presentation logic. If you have a lot of private methods performing business logic in your UI, you've tightly coupled your business logic to your presentation. Start identifying these and moving them out to separate classes with public interfaces that you can test. Read up on [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, which can help you keep your code loosely coupled and testable.

Comment: As for #1: Not only is it not a great option because it's slow, it also isn't even Unit Testing.  UI Testing is just that, it's closer to integration testing.  As for #2: Not only if you have "a lot" of private methods, but if you have ANY Private methods performing business logic have you coupled your code.  Coupled is Coupled, there shouldn't be a scale.  Other than that, #2 is exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing the View is simple enough using approvaltests ( www.approvaltests.com or nuget). there is a video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKeKBjoSfJ8

However, it also seems like you are worried about making a function default or public for the purposes of being able to test functionality.

These are usually referred to as seams; ways to get into your code for testing. 
and they are good. Sometime people confuse private/public with security, and are afraid to turn a private function public, but reflection will call either, so it's not really secure. Other times people are worried about the API interface to a class. But this only matters if you have a public API, and if you have a winform app, it is probably meant to be the top level (no other consumers are calling it.)

You are the programmer, and as such can design your code to be easy to test. This usually means little more than changing a few methods public and creating a few connivence methods that allow dependences to be passed in.

For example:

```
buttonclick += (o,e)=> {/*somecode*/};
```

is very hard to test.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {/*somecode*/}
```

still hard to test

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {/*somecode*/}
```

easier to test

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { DoSave();}
public void DoSave(){/*somecode*/}
```

Really easy to Test!

This goes double if you need some information from the event. ie.

```
public void ZoomInto(int x, int y)
```

is much easier to test that the corresponding mouse click event, and the passthrough call can still be a single ignorable line.

Comment: Some people confuse reasons why bad reasons might be negligible with reasons to do something right.  Encapsulation is for more than just security.  The moment coders think it's okay to make would-be encapsulated members public is the time they lose separation of concerns and solid development practices.  Now you have an app that may not have lost security, but is not as easy to maintain, and employs workarounds to testing instead of just doing it right.

Comment: when the private goes public things are harder to maintain...

I often wonder how that would apply to all the languages that don't have public/private such as ruby/javascript/etc...

Comment: When choosing a language, you think about more than the hardware it can run on, and the strengths of the maintainers of the code base. You also consider the strengths of the language. C#'s main strengths include being type-safe, garbage-collected, generic, friendly native constructs, etc etc. Just because another language (with its own strengths) doesn't match a comment made about C# doesn't mean that comment is relevant. Javascript's main strength is that it is NOT Type-safe. That's best for the problems it solves. Also, you can very well have private members in javascript.

Comment: Point being: If you're using C#, program using C# Object-Oriented techniques.  Yes, you can use a procedural or non-encapsulated approach to cheaply work around issues.  Or, you could just figure out the C# way to do it since you're using C#.  Don't make the mistake of thinking all languages are the same.

Comment: -1. As with the above comments, this is a bad practice, and quickly leads to difficult to maintain code. It is never a good idea to make an item public purely for testing. A better alternative is to use the internal access modifier, and the InternalsVisibleTo attribute to expose these items to your tests.

Comment: The above is just dogmatism. internal is as good as public for code in the same assembly and since we're talking about a top-level assembly that only a unit test will ever reference there's no real advantage to making them internal besides 'purity'. If this were a class library using internal and InternalsVisibleTo would be worth using.

Answer (score 1):

One may employ the MVVM (Model–View–ViewModel) pattern with Reactive.UI, to author testable WinForms code. To get the separation of concerns really need. See: Reactive.UI https://reactiveui.net/  The main downside of using Winforms / MVVM / Reactive.UI is that there are not a lot of examples of its use (for WinForms). The upside is that it is applicable to just about all desktop frameworks and languages. You learn it for one, but the principles apply for all.  When you have lots of private methods, that's OK. IMHO: try to use public methods to begin a business process you want to test. You can use tell-don't-ask: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html and still keep all those methods private.

One may also test the code by driving the UI but this is not so highly recommended, because the resultant tests are (1) very fragile, (2) harder to get working, and IMHO, (3) can't be written at the same level of fine granuality as pure code tests; (4) Finally: if you use a database, you will need to consider populating it with test data, and, because your database must be in a clean, well-defined state before each test, (5) your tests may run even slower than your thought as you reinitialize the data for each test.

Summary: Author your code with good SoC (e.g. by applying MVVM), then your code will have far better testability.