# "no such element" error while trying to capture label button's text using Selenium webdriver with .NET

Tags: .net, selenium, webforms, capture, element

I am trying to automate UI using Selenium WebDriver with .NET and I want to read values of elements like textbox, button etc. thru' automation.

As a sample, I created two web projects in VS2012(project A and Project B). Then I created a webform (textForm.aspx) in proj A, I created a label on this webform. Now, I am trying to read the value assigned to the label in Project B (thru' a class named Program.cs)

Label definition in textForm.aspx is as follows:

Hello

Project B code (program.cs) is as follows:

```
namespace mySeleniumTry
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("e:\\chromedriver");

            string filename = "C:/mySeleniumTry/Program.cs";
            string pathstr = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
            Console.WriteLine("Path of URL is: " + pathstr);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome", pathstr.ToString());
            string lname = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='Label1']")).ToString(); //this line errors
            Console.WriteLine("THE END"+lname.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

'lname' variable is null, there is run time error: no such element (NoSuchElementExeception was unhandled)

Comment: You are trying to navigate to a .CS file using Selenium?!

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to automate C Sharp files using Selenium.  Straight from the [selenium HQ site](http://seleniumhq.org)...

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it.

What it sounds like you are trying to do, is [C# Reflection](https://www.google.com/#q=C#+Reflection) or just a [simple unit test on WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097044/advice-on-unit-testing-a-windows-forms-application).

Furthermore - i am looking more into what you would like to do.  You are trying to navigate to a csharp using chrome, then automate it?  This is preposterous.. use unit tests!