# UNIT test. How to open the form in the test?

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

There is a Windows Forms application.
When the application starts, the form "Form0" will start.
Form0.ShiwInTaskBar = False;

I want to test the application.
I completed:
- created the project "UnitTestProject1".
- prescribed a link to a solution that I will test.

When testing, the Form0 should open.
The "Form0" class does not have a "Show ()" method.

How to open the form in the test?
**Form0**

```
namespace rsh
{
    public partial class Form0 : Form
    {
        public Form0()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Тест**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

// 
using rsh;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TestsStart
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestStart()
        {
            // Тест "Form0"
             Form0 form0 = new Form0();
            form0.

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: a unit test is not meant to test the UI. It should also run on a build server that is headless (no UI) or even no Windows!

Comment: Does the "rsh" project compile successfully? Any warnings or errors? Anyway as Falco says, what will you expect to be testing by doing this?

Comment: @CodeCaster **1.** Yes.
**2.** No.
**3.** I wanted to check how the application works.

The application has several forms and individual classes.
I thought it was possible to make a test, where to write the execution of logic (data input into a form, pressing buttons). and watch it all.
Can this be done when testing?

**ps.** Sorry if the question is incorrect. I'm a beginner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50691935/3110834

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the code:

You should be directly hitting the code as you are doing white box testing. You'll not be able to touch the UI side.

If you want to test the UI:

Please use a tool to interact with the UI of an Windows application:

[Click Here..](https://opensourceforu.com/2018/06/winium-a-selenium-based-windows-automation-tool/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible if you for your own testing

1.- In your testing project add the System.Windows.Forms reference (References section)

2.- do the below:

```
        Form0 form0 = new Form0();
        form0.ShowDialog();
```